# How to re-shuffle data in Cassandra when adding a new node?

Tags: cassandra

I need to add more nodes to our Cassandra cluster but it is unclear to me how to do this properly based on the doc:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

How do I know if the cluster is using vnodes? We are using it with num_tokens 256 and we only have 3 nodes. I guess if you have that it means we have vnodes.

Is there an easy way to re-shuffle the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra version 1.2 and higher by default uses vnodes (256 vnodes), which splits a nodes token into multiple sub tokens to make data distribution evenly to all nodes in a balanced manner.

Each vnode will be assigned a token. So you can find how many vnodes assigned in configuration file or using nodetool.

As you have said "num_tokens" tells number of vnodes in that Cassandra node.

(or)

Execute nodetool ring command which will list the tokens in your cluster for each node.

```
nodetool ring
```

It is recommended to use vnodes which will balance your cluster. Earlier Cassandra versions lesser than 1.1 does not have vnodes, So we used to generate the tokens and configured in initial_token parameter available in cassandra.yaml file.

Hence in Cassandra versions 1.2 or higher, using of vnodes is enough to balance the cluster, no need for re-shuffle data.